# Computer screen sometimes won't turn on but computer appears to boot normally

Tags: display, gpu

Sometimes my computer screen won't turn on but computer appears to boot normally. I have cleaned my motherboard ect. with just the basic stuff to boot/start up. After a couple of restart times,or if the screen wont turn on - I will turn the computer on later and then it display normally. Daily I use my computer and it will startup fine but suddenly (after a couple or one days) the screen won't turn on at startup. I think it must be my graphic card?

Can some one please help me because I am not so familiar with computer errors.

Thanks

Comment: Start with the basics - if you're using a video card, check if your motherboard has onboard video and try that. And/or if any other video ports are available (hdmi/dvi/vga) try one of them instead. It wouldn't hurt to test the monitor on another PC if you can too. Make sure cables are plugged in properly.

Comment: I have the computer from 2015 and it work fine until the last couple of months. My Pc will be good for a few days even sometimes for a few weeks and all randomly my Pc wouldn't turn on. I have a i7 with a Geforce 9600 Gt graphic card. It is not the monitor - I have change it. If I turn om my PC, it normally make a softly beep noise, before the display appear/monitor is on. My computer boot up fine, it is only the display. I have cleaned every thing inside the computer box - and used just the basic - like one hard drive ect. I think it must be the graphic card. If appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you say your screen won't turn on, are you saying it won't turn on at any moment or the screen turns on before the OS boots then it remains blank?

If the first, this could be your motherboard not passing on [POST](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test). There are many things that could be causing this, like a specific peripheral, an expansion card (like a graphics card) and even your motherboard itself.

If the second, could be a faulty OS installation. I recommend trying to restore your OS to a previous point or reinstall the enitre OS.